# What's that site that frames screenshots in iPhone/iPad/Mac stock photos?

Tags: photos, screen-capture, image-editing

Late last year in 2012, someone had launched a site that let you upload screenshots (or any image really) and it would embed them into nice stock photos of a Apple phone, tablet or laptop/desktop. It was basically designed for someone making a product web site and wanted to feature shots of the app or web site running on those devices. There was even a shot of a person holding an iPhone in their hands.

I can't for the life of me remember the name of the site though, and googling isn't helping me. A friend thinks it might have the words 'showoff' in it, but no luck either with that phrase.

Anyone remember?

Comment: I know there are several iOS apps that do this, but that's not what I'm after. This was a very elegant, minimal and to the point, free site. It's not Boxshot King either, I think it was Apple specific.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It sounds like you’re describing [PlaceIt](http://placeit.breezi.com).

Comment: It seems to be it but sadly it grew a bit too much for my taste. The original version was much simpler. Less choice, but more straightforward... it also seemed to me that the images were completely free to use, but I might be mistaken. Either way, thanks Andrew!

Comment: @TimothéeBoucher, yeah, they seem to have updated the site in just the past few weeks, and it's significantly more complex now. They also seem to be charging for use of certain images now. Still a useful tool, but I did like it better before.

Comment: How, that evolution is heartbreaking. It used to be a beautiful product. And none of the other services that popped up to do the same job comes remotely close.

Answer (score 12):

Here's what I found. Some are free, some aren't.

- [placeit.net](https://placeit.net)
- [agicmockups.com](http://magicmockups.com)
- [psdcovers.com/category/action/mockups/apple](http://www.psdcovers.com/category/action/mockups/apple)
- [appdemostore.com/frameapp](http://www.appdemostore.com/frameapp)
- [graphicriver.net/category/graphics/product-mock-ups/displays](http://graphicriver.net/category/graphics/product-mock-ups/displays)
- [picapp.net](http://picapp.net)
- [Scenery](https://www.getscenery.com)

Comment: PlaceIt is quite expensive but has lots of features but what I personally like is [MagicMockups](http://magicmockups.com/) and [MockupsJar](http://mockupsjar.com/) which are very easy to use and I hope they will add more features in time.

Answer (score 8):

PlaceIt is really powerful if you can afford it. But I like [Frame App](http://www.appdemostore.com/frameapp) - it's free and fast and works well. No fancy backgrounds, just mockups.

Answer (score 3):

I use [iSweetIt](http://www.isweetit.com), it is an app that you can use offline too, and has a lot of templates like phones and notebooks but also print and posters. It's fast and it works.

Comment: Great tool for free!

Comment: Just a note as of 12/19/17 the iSweetIt site is dead.

Answer (score 0):

[ScreenShot builder](https://launchkit.io/screenshots) is free, and is very simple to use.
No iPad screenshots (in May 2015) - but it is great for iPhones.

Answer (score 0):

I can also add these alternatives:

- http://iphone-screenshot.com/
- http://mockuphone.com/

Answer (score 0):

[mockupsjar.com](http://mockupsjar.com) - Create realistic mockups for your website and mobile app in 3 steps for free.